# PHP header function not triggering?

Tags: php

I'm getting some fairly odd behavior here... I noticed that only localhost, a header statement I have worked just fine, but when copied over (SAME EXACT CODE) to my live site, the header statement no longer triggers.

I added some echos to help debug. This if statement will only trigger if the URL variable `id` is NOT set. So with this same exact code on localhost, I never see these debug statements. On the live site, I do... which I shouldn't. I should get redirected instead. Anyone know why a header statement would be ignored?

```
if((!isset($_GET['id'])) && $rows != 0) {
      $result = mysql_query('SELECT videoinfo FROM videos where game_id=' . $gameid . ' LIMIT 1');
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      $tubeID = $row['videoinfo'];
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location = "videos.php?id=' . $tubeID . '&awayid=' . $awayid . '&homeid=' . $homeid . '&date=' . $date . '&time=' . $time . '&gameid=' . $gameid . '&play=0"';
      echo '</script>';
}
```

**EDIT** 4 people have told me already that I can't have any echo calls before my header function. This code WORKS on localhost and the header function DOES trigger. Regardless, REMOVING the echo statements DOES NOT fix it.

Comment: @genesis Could you be a little more specific? I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK

Can't send header() after some echo.

Comment: You're nearly the 4th person to tell me this. Then explain to me why it worked on localhost with the echo calls. Even so, removing the echos didnt fix it.

Comment: Maybe the header is not the problem itself. Try 'turning on' all errors for display'?? error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1')

Comment: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ec2-user/public_html/videos.php:25) in /home/ec2-user/public_html/displayvideos.php on line 36` Line 36 is where the header statement is

Comment: There you go, something is wrong or misconfigured 'cause header has been sent already. Try to use javascript to redirect?

Comment: Is not the best workaround though, but hey! it works :P. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot output ANYTHING before you call header(), i.e. echo etc...

Comment: I don't think that's entirely true, the same code worked just fine for me on localhost. Regardless, removing the echo statements did not fix the issue.

Comment: Perhaps a read of the manual then :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php like this note at top of page "Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(), functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have a header after any sort of output. I just came up with that.

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/archive/7/73/20110128203738!Trollface.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable output buffering.  This is probably enabled on your localhost but not on your live system (or the value on the live system is too small).

This will keep your output buffered, and then the Header will work fine.

Your debug statements are making the problem worse.

Answer (score 0):

`header` statements will not work if there is any output before they are called.  In this case, your `echo`s are killing it.  Also, make sure there is no other output before this is called (white space, HTML, etc.).

Comment: I don't think that's entirely true, the same code worked just fine for me on localhost. Regardless, removing the echo statements did not fix the issue.

Comment: @Tory: Make there there is no other output before `header` is called.  White space before the `<?php` could cause this.

Comment: @Tory: Weird.  It shouldn't, obviously.  Your localhost is definitely set up incorrectly.

Comment: @Tory: Try calling [`headers_sent()`](http://php.net/headers_sent) to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

at start of script, add

```
ob_start();
```

and just before calling header();, use

```
ob_clean();
```

---

```
  ob_clean();
  header('Location: videos.php?id=' . $tubeID . '&awayid=' . $awayid . '&homeid=' . $homeid . '&date=' . $date . '&time=' . $time . '&gameid=' . $gameid . '&play=0');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Check to ensure that your files are encoded correctly.  For instance, if you are encoding in UTF-8, make sure you encode in UTF-8 without BOM (Byte Order Mark).

How to check depends on what you use to edit and save your file.  For instance, I use Notepad++ so I just go to the 'Encoding' menu and select 'Encode in UTF-8 without BOM' and then save the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
function goto_url($url) {

// must not have output anything prior to calling this function

        if (!headers_sent()){

            header('Location: '.$url); exit;

        } else { 
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

            echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';

            echo '</script>';

            echo '<noscript>';

            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';

            echo '</noscript>'; exit;

        };

};
```

**http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_headers_sent.asp**